# Resent email verification link not changing verified to true

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm setting up a custom authentication system  in my meteor app.

When a user signs up, they are sent an email verification link. If they click on this, it changes the verification boolean to true as expected.

I have a button in the users account setting page that allows them to resend a verification email if needed. Clicking on this works ok and they receive another email with a different link.

When this new link is clicked, it redirects to the home page but it doesn't verify the email address.

My guess is that the users account isn't aware of the new token.

```
//server code
Meteor.methods({
  'sendVerificationEmail' : function(userId, primaryEmail){
    var userId = Meteor.user();
    Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userId, primaryEmail, function (error) {
    if (! error) {
      return alert('Verfication email sent');
    } else {
      return alert(error);
      };
    });
  }
});

//Client code
Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink(function (token, done) {
  Accounts.verifyEmail(token, function (error) {
    if (! error) {
      console.log('Account verified');
      alert('Account verified');
    }

    done();
    // show something if there was an error.
  });
});

// Email verification route
Router.route('/verify-email/:token', {
  name: 'verifyEmail'
});
```

Comment: What does the "resend verification email" do? Please share the relevant code.

Comment: @MasterAM Calls a method on the server. [code on JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3385s3zn/1/)

Comment: There are some issues in your code, but none of them should prevent the email from being verified. Note, however: 1. `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail` expects the userId and you provide the entire user object; 2. It has no callback; 3. Even if it had one, you cannot simply return a value from callback in a Meteor method. 4. Even if you could, you are returning the return value of an `alert` (?!) call. 5. Logging the error in the `verifyEmail()` callback might be useful for debugging.

Comment: Have the exact same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780001/cant-validate-email-token-when-calling-accounts-sendverificationemail-a-second?noredirect=1#comment59240997_35780001), did you manage to find a solution to this?