# Can't validate email token when calling Accounts.sendVerificationEmail a second time

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I installed a process of email address verification using Meteor Accounts. It works fine, but when `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail()` is called a second time, the `Account.verifyEmail()` method always refuse with a 403: `Verify email link expired` when called on the new token.

The email verification token set in Meteor.users by the first call to `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail()` is not changed when calling that method again: It's still the link sent with the first email that will work.

I can't find any info related to this in the Meteor documentation or on the internet. Is there something to do before beeing able to call `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail()` a second time (like cleanup or something?).

Comment: Tokens should be added to an array in the user's document. You can look at the user's document in the database and see whether they have already confirmed their email or get clues to this behavior. You can also take a look at the accounts-password source code in the Meteor repository.

Comment: Yeah i took a look at this. It seems that the token that is sent with the new mail is the one that is set in the Meteor.user collection. The verifyEmail function is probably failing for another reason, but i don't understand why, the stack gets quite complicated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue implementing the resend link to my website. I got around this by removing all the previous `verficationTokens`.

Here are two methods of applying a fix to this problem:

1. This is the preferred method if you already have an active database with ***n*** amount of users having trouble verifying their accounts. Place this code in a separate `Meteor.call()` method after you call the `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail()` method:
   `Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {'$push': services.email.verificationTokens": {$each: [], $slice: -1}}});`

This will empty all the other tokens except for the last token created by the latest call to `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail()` method.

2. This method may be quicker for implementing newer projects or when implementing `meteor-accounts` in a new project. Similar to step 1) place this code in a new `Meteor.call()` method and call it after calling `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail()` method:
   `Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {'$pop': {"services.email.verificationTokens": -1}});`

This will pop the first entry of the `verificationTokens` and thus the only entry is left with the latest token generated in `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail()` method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing something similar. Thx for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you use sendVerificationEmail(), a new entry appears in users collection : 'services.email.verificationTokens' and you'll see in 'emails.[x].verified' is false.
When you use verifyEmail(), the 'emails.[x].verified' go to true, and values in 'services.email.verificationTokens' disappear. So, if you try to use a second time verifyEmail(), it can't because email still verified and verification token is delete. 
If you send a second time sendVerificationEmail() with a new token, the new link allows you to use verifyEmail() without error message.

Comment: This is true (i guess), but the problem here is that i didn't call verifyEmail after the first **sendVerificationEmail()**. The user didn't click on the first link, that's why he's asking for another verification email. My problem is that calling sendVerificationEmail() twice in a row doesn't seem to reset the token in MongoDB, and it's still the first link that will validate the user email.